# Accessing a benchmark's result

Tags: go, benchmarking

I've seen there is a struct [`testing.BenchmarkResult`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing#BenchmarkResult) in Go to accesss the result of a benchmark but I found very little documentation or examples to help me use it.

So far I have only been benchmarking my functions like this:

```
func BenchmarkMyFunction(b *testing.B) {
   // call to myFunction
}
```

And then running:

```
go test -bench=".*"
```

Here the results are printed to the console but I'd like to store them in a separate file. How can I use the `BenchmarkResult` type to do this?

Comment: Just redirect stdout to a file in your shell.

Comment: Note benchmarks need to look over `b.N` to be useful. See https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks

Comment: Also, as recommended in the documentation, you can use just `go test -bench=.` to run all benchmarks. This avoids the need to escape/quote `*` from the shell.

Comment: There is also the `-json` flag to `go test` (added in [Go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#test)) which outputs results in a machine parse-able JSON format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func Add(a, b int) int {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Microsecond) // Just to make the test take some time
    return a + b
}

func BenchAdd(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = Add(1, 2)
    }
}

func main() {
    res := testing.Benchmark(BenchAdd)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n%#[1]v\n", res)
}
```

Produces:

```
  120000         10000 ns/op
testing.BenchmarkResult{N:120000, T:1200000000, Bytes:0, MemAllocs:0x0, MemBytes:0x0, Extra:map[string]float64{}}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/J08d1EtHcfC).

You can easily write these results out to a file using [`ioutil.WriteFile`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile).
[Playground w/ WriteFile](https://play.golang.org/p/K1Djic0Ju0o).